# Concern about Depth First Search

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Prove that if G is an undirected connected graph, then each of its edges is either in the depth-first search tree or is a back edge.

Now, from intuition and in class lectures by Steven Skiena, I know that the above holds true, since it dives all the way down, and then throw a rope back to a previous vertex. I also know that DFS is great in finding cycles.

However, my problem here is that I don't know how to 'prove' that the edge is either a tree edge or a back edge.

Comment: you might get a better answer over at the CS stack exchange: http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the 4 cases possible (theoretically). An edge can be:

1. A tree edge
2. A back edge
3. Both a tree edge and a back edge
4. Neither a tree edge or a back edge

To prove what is needed, you need to show that cases 3 and 4 cannot happen, i.e. lead to a contradiction.

Comment: Why doesn't he have to cover the case of forward edges?

Comment: @G.Bach The task, as he stated, was to prove that every edge is either a tree edge or a back edge. These are the only four possible cases with respect to this classification. Other types of edges may or may not help him in showing that cases 3 and 4 are not possible.